# Deploying spring boot project war on JBoss7.1.1

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, jboss

I want use spring boot in my new project but dont want its inbuilt tomcat server. I want to use jboss server. I have created war file but not able to deploy on jboss server

pom.xml of my project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.prabhat.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootsample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>bootsample</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I deployed war file on my jboss server through eclipse and it showing me exception while starting the server

> 5:33:48,738 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."bootsample.war".WeldService:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."bootsample.war".WeldService:
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputationException:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3   at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] Caused by:
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputationException:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3   at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.(WeldClassImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.(WeldClassImpl.java:139)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:86)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
>     at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)     at
>   org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)     ...
>   5 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldConstructorImpl.(WeldConstructorImpl.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldConstructorImpl.of(WeldConstructorImpl.java:66)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.(WeldClassImpl.java:205)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
>     ... 32 more

Comment: please read this post [Unable to Deploy in Jboss](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/224083)

Comment: where to find this beans.xml file in spring boot project? Or i have to make this xml file? please suggest